# How do I mail the output of a kubernetes cronjob?

Tags: kubernetes, openshift, kubernetes-cronjob

I've setup a cronjob in Openshift. I can see its logs through the Web Console but I want to receive a mail containing the output of the job whenever it completes. How do I go about implementing this?

Answer (score 1):

There are no built-in instruments for such kind of reporting. You will need to implement own cronjob wrapper which emails you a result.

Kubernetes wasn't designed as a full-featured scheduled job runner, cron jobs are just one of the API extensions added later, and it's still in beta.

Comment: cronjobs are GA in Openshift 3.9 (TP in 3.6 + 3.7)
https://docs.openshift.com/container-platform/3.9/release_notes/ocp_3_9_release_notes.html#ocp-39-technology-preview

Answer (score 1):

You can add sth. like "mailx" to your cronjob image and forward the output.

In the following example "mailgateway.default.svc" is a service route to a mailgateway outside the cluster:

```
<output_producing_command> | mailx -E -v -s "Subject" -S smtp=smtp://mailgateway.default.svc:25 -S from="foo.bar@baz.com (Foo Bar)" abc.def@ghi.com 2>&1
```

> -E     If an outgoing message does not contain any text in its first or only message part, do not send  it  but  discard  it  silently, 
>   effectively  setting  the
>                 skipemptybody variable at program startup.  This is useful for sending messages from scripts started by cron(8).